# Libgdx Creating fast maps without TiledMap

Tags: java, performance, random, dictionary, libgdx

i am trying to make A game like Minecraft (in 2D).
I dont wanna use TiledMap,
becouse it cant (ive didnt found a way how) generate random maps.

My Test & code:

```
public class game implements ApplicationListener {
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;

    private Sprite block[] = new Sprite[26];
    private int createdBlocks = 0;
    private int line = 0;
    @Override
    public void create() {      
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(w, h);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        camera.position.x = 480;
        camera.position.y = 320;
        camera.update();

        graphics.create();
        player.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        for(int i=0; i<=25;i++){        
            block[i] = new Sprite(graphics.stone);
            if(i==5 || i==10 || i==15 || i==20)
            line++;
            int i2 = i;
            if(i > 5)
            i = 0;
            block[i].setPosition(i2 * 32, line * 32);
        }
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        player.render(batch);
        for(int i=0; i<=100;i++)
        block[i].draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

its just lagging, slow (loading) and not usefull.

is there a better way?

Comment: You're reinitializing 25 new Sprite(stones) every single time you render, which might have something to do with why it's lagging so much. Move that for loop at the top of the render method into the create method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**About your code:**

You create lots of new sprites every frame (your loop inside `render()` method). You should create your sprites in other place, probably in `create()` method.

**About creating map without TiledMap:**

You can use `SpriteCache` instead `SpriteBatch` for building tile based terrain. You can take a look at example of using `SpriteCache` [here](http://www.rengelbert.com/tutorial.php?id=178)

**About random generation of TiledMap**

`.tmx` file - is just XML structured file. You can generate it in code as you want with any XML parser, that's why creating a random TiledMap is not a problem. Here is some basic instructions:

1. Create tile sets for your random maps.
2. Create an example map with this sets in tmx editor.
3. Open it with any text editor and a take a look at file structure.
4. Generate a similar file in code with any XML parser (you can use libgdx built in [parser](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-xml))

P.S I don't recommend you to develop your own solution for 2D maps, in 90% of cases tmx is more than enough for creating 2D maps. You also already have optimized tmx render class inside libgdx.

Comment: @AUser welcome if the answer helps your problem consider upvote if you do not know how or why read this thanks http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thanks! But ive found a another way! ;)  batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
  batch.begin();
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
   for(int i2=0;i2<100;i2++){
    batch.draw(graphics.stone, 32*i2, 32*i);
   }
  }
  player.render(batch);
  batch.end();